# Tesseract Image Issue

Tags: tesseract

After I installed the tesseract on centos, I am getting the following error,

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.05.00dev with Leptonica
Error in pixReadMemJpeg: function not present
Error in pixReadMem: jpeg: no pix returned
Error during processing.
```

Answer (score 10):

I solved this problem. The reason is that you do not install the libjpeg, libtiff, libpng before compile the leptonica.
Step 1: Install libjpeg, libtiff, libpng.
Step 2: Recompile and install the leptonica.
[more links](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/issues/detail?id=391)

Comment: Could you please provide exact steps for this? Where to get those from, what to run in terminal. Can these be globally installed using npm?

Answer (score 2):

Default image format for **firstly tesseract version** was .tif or .tiff. in new version you should install following format package (**libgif libjpeg libpng libtiff zlib**). **Leptonica** use this pakages for read images and **tesseract** use **leptonica** for analyse images.

> libgif  libjpeg  libpng  libtiff  zlib

finally recompile and install leptonica as @BigBen answer.

Answer (score 1):

Leptonica complains if its optional dependencies are not present. You can silence these errors by recompiling leptonica with the macro `NO_CONSOLE_IO`. For more information, see leptonica source code, file `environ.h`.

Answer (score 0):

For future people who get here:

I was using `os.listdir()` to enumerate the files within a directory, but one of the cases I hadn't considered was that a **directory** within the results of `os.listdir()` was matching the naming pattern I was filtering on.

Adding an additional condition as follows worked for me:

```py
for item in os.listdir():
    if "name" in item and os.path.isfile(item):
         # do stuff
```

The important thing to add is a condition that checks it is a file, `os.path.isfile(item)`.

Ideally you should check that it is an *image file*, because the error here is that the file being processed ***is not an image file***